# Is it possible to delete or overwrite document in BIM360 Docs using API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

When we upload the document in BIM360 docs folder, the document is not overwritten if it exists already.

What we want to do is, if a document already exists. then upload code should be overwritten the document.
Or delete the existed document and upload a new one.

We have not found any API which can delete BIM360 docs.

Comment: Which folder did you upload? In project files folder, you have to upload files with the same file name and extension. Otherwise, it will be treated as new file.

Comment: In Plans folder, the number field of the OCR processing must the same, it will become the file name of the upload files such as PDF, DWG, DXF, RVT and so on. Otherwise, it will be considered as the different file. However, it would be the combination of the number + title of the OCR template if your BIM360 project was not created recently with my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove items from BIM360 Docs' folder, please call [POST projects/:project_id/versions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/) with this body and fresh your web browser if you're opening the folder page that contains this item, then you will see it has been moved into "Deleted Items":

```
{ 
   "jsonapi":{ 
      "version":"1.0"
   },
   "data":{ 
      "type":"versions",
      "attributes":{ 
         "extension":{ 
            "type":"versions:autodesk.core:Deleted",      //!<<< The key of this action
            "version":"1.0"
         }
      },
      "relationships":{ 
         "item":{ 
            "data":{ 
               "type":"items",
               "id":"{{ItemId}}"                          //!<<< e.g. urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:8ucohSiktGeEqDn4SX75cA of id of the item you want to delete
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Note.** Files uploaded onto BIM360 Docs are not deletable really, all of them are just hidden or moved into the "Deleted Items" after calling this API or clicking delete button on the BIM360 Web UI.